# JavaFX: How to group shapes for dragging?

Tags: javafx, grouping, shapes

How can I group shapes (e.g. circles) in JavaFX for dragging them around? The example code is based on the Oracle tutorial. Each single circle can be moved. I want to move the blue circle alone when dragging it. I want to move the green and the blue circle when clicking and dragging the green one and all three of them when clicking and dragging the red one. Any ideas?

```
public class DragGroupSample extends Application {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        launch();
    }

    private void makeDraggable( Circle circle ) {
        DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();

        // --- remember initial coordinates of mouse cursor and node
        circle.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (
                final MouseEvent mouseEvent ) -> {
            dragContext.dx = mouseEvent.getX() - circle.getCenterX();
            dragContext.dy = mouseEvent.getY() - circle.getCenterY();
        } );

        // --- Shift node calculated from mouse cursor movement
        circle.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, (
                final MouseEvent mouseEvent ) -> {
            circle.setCenterX( mouseEvent.getX() + dragContext.dx );
            circle.setCenterY( mouseEvent.getY() + dragContext.dy );
        } );

        // --- Drop card onto allowed target field
        circle.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, (
                final MouseEvent mouseEvent ) -> {
            circle.setCenterX( mouseEvent.getX() + dragContext.dx );
            circle.setCenterY( mouseEvent.getY() + dragContext.dy );
        } );
    }

    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception {
        Circle[] circles = new Circle[3];
        circles[0] = new Circle( 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, Color.RED );
        circles[1] = new Circle( 45.0, 45.0, 30.0, Color.GREEN );
        circles[2] = new Circle( 60.0, 60.0, 30.0, Color.BLUE );
        for ( Circle circle : circles ) {
            makeDraggable( circle );
        }

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().addAll( circles[0], circles[1], circles[2] );
        primaryStage.setResizable( false );
        primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( root, 400, 350 ) );
        primaryStage.setTitle( DragGroupSample.class.getSimpleName() );
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static final class DragContext {
        public double dx, dy;
    }
}
```

Comment: What James_D said. Or you could as well take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300067/drag-nodes-like-in-a-patience-klondike-card-game which is similar to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Just move all the circles you want to move. It's probably easier to store the last mouse location relative to something fixed (like the scene), instead of working relative to the circle.

Here's one way, there are many:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragGroupSample extends Application {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        launch();
    }

    // list of nodes that are dragged. Can be modified at any time (on the FX Application Thread):
    private final List<Circle> nodesToDrag = new ArrayList<>();

    private final Circle[] circles = new Circle[3] ;

    private void makeDraggable( Circle circle ) {
        MouseLocation lastMouseLocation = new MouseLocation();

        // --- remember initial coordinates of mouse cursor and node
        circle.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (
                final MouseEvent mouseEvent ) -> {
            lastMouseLocation.x = mouseEvent.getSceneX() ;
            lastMouseLocation.y = mouseEvent.getSceneY() ;

            // just some example logic to modify the list of dragged nodes:
            boolean found = false ;
            for (Circle c : circles) {
                if (c == circle) found = true ;
                if (found) nodesToDrag.add(c);
            }
        } );

        // --- Shift node calculated from mouse cursor movement
        circle.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, (
                final MouseEvent mouseEvent ) -> {
                    double deltaX = mouseEvent.getSceneX() - lastMouseLocation.x ;
                    double deltaY = mouseEvent.getSceneY() - lastMouseLocation.y ;
                    for (Circle c : nodesToDrag) {
                        c.setCenterX( c.getCenterX() + deltaX  );
                        c.setCenterY( c.getCenterY() + deltaY );
                    }
                    lastMouseLocation.x = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
                    lastMouseLocation.y = mouseEvent.getSceneY();
        } );

        circle.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, mouseEvent -> nodesToDrag.clear());

    }

    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception {

        circles[0] = new Circle( 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, Color.RED );
        circles[1] = new Circle( 45.0, 45.0, 30.0, Color.GREEN );
        circles[2] = new Circle( 60.0, 60.0, 30.0, Color.BLUE );

        for ( Circle circle : circles ) {
            makeDraggable( circle );
        }

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().addAll( circles[0], circles[1], circles[2] );
        primaryStage.setResizable( false );
        primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( root, 400, 350 ) );
        primaryStage.setTitle( DragGroupSample.class.getSimpleName() );
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static final class MouseLocation {
        public double x, y;
    }
}
```

Comment: So the solution is to apply the mouse movement to all shapes involved. I hoped that I could dynamically create a Group, add some children to it and then move the group around with JavaFX automatically applying the mouse movement to all children of the group. The number of circles (shapes) from my example changes over time, so I cannot preallocate some fixed lists. Thanks for your ideas

Comment: I thought about doing it that way, and you can probably make it work, but it just ends up being (much) more complicated. To change what's in the "dragging group", you have to remove the circles from their existing parent first, and then add them to the group. Then at some point (mouse release, perhaps), you need to move them out of the dragging group and put them back into the parent, and make sure they preserve the translation that was applied to the group...

Comment: Also note that nothing in my solution prevents you from dynamically updating the list(s) of nodes that are going to be dragged. Here I actually keep three such lists, referenced in a map, but you can keep one if you need and modify it with any logic you want. I'll modify the solution to do it more like that...