# Moving a button to specified coordinates in JavaFX with a Path Transition using LineTo, MoveTo

Tags: java, animation, button, javafx, transition

I'm making an animation that involves moving buttons representing data travelling in a network. So far, I've been able to move the buttons to different locations at different stages of the animation by updating their LayoutX and LayoutY fields, and by using sequential transitions.

But now I'm trying to get the button, named blue, to move in a diagonal line from its position at a stage to "router 3," which is up and to the right of the button. The exact Layout coordinates of the destination are 426(x) and 364(y), and the Layout coordinates of the starting position are 309(x) and 585(y). I've been trying to use moveTo with LineTo to get the button to the aforementioned coordinates, but it's proving difficult for two reasons:

**First,** I use a transition to get to the starting coordinates, so the actual coordinates of the button by the time it reaches the starting position are LayoutX: 14,  LayoutY: 445, TranslateX: 295, TranslateY: 140.
I try and rectify this with the code:

```
        blue.setLayoutX(blue.getLayoutX() + blue.getTranslateX());
        blue.setLayoutY(blue.getLayoutY() + blue.getTranslateY());
        blue.setTranslateX(0);
        blue.setTranslateY(0);
```

And then define the path for blue to follow as:

```
        Path path = new Path();
        MoveTo start = new MoveTo();
        start.setX(blue.getTranslateX());
        start.setY(blue.getTranslateY());
        path.getElements().add(start);
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(125.0f, -220.0f));
        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
        pathTransition.setPath(path);
        pathTransition.setNode(blue);
        pathTransition.setCycleCount((int) 1f);
        pathTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
        pathTransition.play();
```

But this seems like a cumbersome workaround. For instance, the next stage of this program has the buttons traversing a network of multiple "routers" according to Dijkstra's algorithm, and I'd like to be able to just have a line path defined that goes straight to the next router, without having to fiddle with Translation and Layout coordinates at every stage. Alternatively, Swing, for instance, can repaint a circle while its coordinates are updated pixel by pixel, so as to make a diagonal animation and to stop after reaching a certain position. Is this possible using JavaFX?

**Secondly,** Even when this animation as it is implemented begins, the button seems to "jump back" slightly, as though the start of the path to be traveled is a couple pixels down and to the left of where the button actually is, even though as far as I can tell I've specified the start of the path to be exactly where the button is before the animation begins. Is there a particular reason for this?

Thank you for any help related to my question; It's my first time using StackOverflow. I was pretty sure I'd scoured for an answer to this kind of question quite thoroughly but I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known problem, you can read about it in the [Create a path transition with absolute coordinates for a StackPane object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659474/create-a-path-transition-with-absolute-coordinates-for-a-stackpane-object/27729231#27729231) thread.

Unfortunately you have to work around that problem, there is no solution inside JavaFX. Fortunately the solution is easy, just use a modified version of MoveTo and LineTo.

Here's a modified example code for you. Just click on a position in your scene and the node will move there without "jumping".

```
public class PathTransitionExample extends Application {

    PathTransition transition;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Group root = new Group();

        // create movable object
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50);
        rect.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        rect.setFill(Color.BLUE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3));
        rect.relocate(100, 80);
        root.getChildren().add(rect);

        Label label = new Label("Click on scene to set destination");
        label.relocate(0, 0);
        root.getChildren().add(label);

        // init transition
        transition = new PathTransition();
        transition.setNode(rect);
        transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 768);

        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<Event>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {

                transition.stop();

                setPositionFixed( rect);

                double toX = ((MouseEvent) event).getX();
                double toY = ((MouseEvent) event).getY();

                Path path = new Path();
                path.getElements().add(new MoveToAbs(rect));
                path.getElements().add(new LineToAbs(rect, toX, toY));

                transition.setPath(path);
                transition.play();

            }

            // change layout to current position, reset translate
            private void setPositionFixed( Node node) {
                double x = rect.getLayoutX() + rect.getTranslateX();
                double y = rect.getLayoutY() + rect.getTranslateY();
                rect.relocate(x, y);
                rect.setTranslateX(0);
                rect.setTranslateY(0);
            }

        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static class MoveToAbs extends MoveTo {

        public MoveToAbs(Node node) {
            super(node.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2, node.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2);
        }

        public MoveToAbs(Node node, double x, double y) {
            super(x - node.getLayoutX() + node.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2, y - node.getLayoutY() + node.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2);
        }

    }

    public static class LineToAbs extends LineTo {

        public LineToAbs(Node node, double x, double y) {
            super(x - node.getLayoutX() + node.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2, y - node.getLayoutY() + node.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly. Thank you very much! Sorry for the duplicate, I guess I didn't quite know how to search for my own question. I'd like to add that, even though my node is circular as opposed to rectangular, a workaround like the one you suggested is still necessary. This might have to do with the fact that I defined its properties in a CSS file, however. I'm not sure. Anyway, Thanks again!